# Firefox CSS Table Extra Border Line

Tags: css, html-table, border, firefox3.6

I encountered a table border line CSS problem in Firefox: when the CSS `border-collapse` is `collapse`, and I have two merged cells, one of them has a 1px border. An extra unwanted border line exists on the right.

This problem does not exist in other browsers, IE and Chrome don't have the problem.

Firefox version is

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT
> 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

My tested doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

---

[image: diagram showing extra border lines]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: absolute; width: 217px; left: 0px;border-collapse:collapse">
<colgroup><col col="0" style="width: 72px;"><col col="1" style="width: 72px;"><col col="2" style="width: 72px;">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr tridx="0" style="height: 19px;">
<td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></td><td row="0" col="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr tridx="1" style="height: 19px;"><td row="1" col="2"></td></tr>
<tr tridx="2" style="height: 19px;"><td row="2" col="0"></td><td row="2" col="1"></td><td row="2" col="2"></td></tr>
<tr tridx="3" style="height: 19px;"><td rowspan="3" colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr tridx="4" style="height: 19px;"><td ></td></tr>
<tr tridx="5" style="height: 19px;"><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My tested doctype is:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> , auto generated by editplus.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a better fix for it, but the problem lies with `colspan` and the use of `border-collapse`.

I re-wrote the code just because it looked messy to me, but basically the solution was to use `border-spacing: 0;` instead of `border-collapse: collapse;`

This isn't perfect because they aren't the same thing. So if all of your cells had borders on them then the ones inside the table would double up creating a 2px border.

However in that situation you wouldn't notice anything and you could use `border-collapse` anyway.

Well, I think I have said enough.

Here is my code (A little different from yours but it does the same thing):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tableStyle {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
.tableStyle td {
 height: 19px;
 width: 72px;
}
.blackBorder {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tableStyle">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="blackBorder">1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3" colspan="2" class="blackBorder">7</td>
  <td>8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>10</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanations and good advice. In fact, not all of my cells had borders on them, but some of them, it depends.
If I use "border-collapse: collapse", table would double up creating 2px borders, else other cells without borders would had extra unwanted borders.